# What does this notation mean: $\vec{f} : [a,b] \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: notation

In particular I don't understand how to interpret the domain.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the $\times $ sign means *Cartesian product* in the context of sets.

Let
$$
A=\{x,y,z \}\qquad B=\{1,2 \}
$$

then the set $C=A\times B$ is the set of all ordered pairs created from the elements of $A$ and $B$, in formal mathematical language

$$
C=\{(a,b)\mid a\in A, b\in B \}.
$$

In the above example $C$ is the set
$$
\{(x,1),(x,2),(y,1),(y,2),(z,1),(z,2) \}.
$$

I hope I could help.

Comment: Thank you. So in this case $[a,b] \times \mathbb{R}^n$ would be like all ordered pairs $(t_1,x_1,\dots,x_n), (t_2,x_1,\dots,x_n), \dots$ for all $t_i \in [a,b]$?

Comment: Yes! Happy that I could help! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The arrow means that we consider a time-dependent *vector* *field*. Hence $f(t,x)$ is a vector at the point $x$ depending on the time $t$. A good example is the wind : at each point of the earth $\bf R^2$ the wind is represented by a vector. This vector gives the direction and strength of the wind at the instant $t$ and at the point $x$.